# (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") in laravel 9 migration

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database-migration

I have two tables in my laravel application.

company table
employee table.

Following is my company table migration file.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('companies', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('logo');
            $table->text('email', 50)->unique();
            $table->string('website');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('companies');
    }
};
```

and the following is the employee table.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('employees', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('first_name');
            $table->string('last_name');
            $table->text('email', 50)->unique();
            $table->text('phone', 50)->unique();
            $table->integer('company_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('company_id')->references('id')->on('companies')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('employees');
    }
};
```

But,

Whenever I tried to run my employee table migration, it kept giving me an error saying,

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table
> `laraapp`.`employees` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is
> incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `employees` add constraint
> `employees_company_id_foreign`  foreign key (`company_id`) references
> `companies` (`id`) on delete cascade)

ID of my company table is UNSIGNED.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value of `$table->id();` is actually `unsignedBigInteger()` but you've defined your `company_id` foreign key column to only be an `unsignedInteger` so the two column types do no match.

As you are using Laravel 9, you can use the [`foreignId()`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#column-method-foreignId) method which will automatically create the column with the correct type:

```
$table->foreignId('company_id');
```

You could also use the [`foreignIdFor()`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#column-method-foreignIdFor) method which will also create the underly required `fk` constraint so you don't have to.

```
$table->foreignIdFor(Company::class);
```

For completeness:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('employees', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('first_name');
            $table->string('last_name');
            $table->text('email', 50)->unique();
            $table->text('phone', 50)->unique();
            $table->foreignIdFor(Company::class);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('employees');
    }
};
```